# SQL Works in SQL Developer but not in Informatica Cloud (IICS)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, informatica, informatica-cloud

I am running the below query in SQL developer and it works there. IICS Source also validates this query and I am able to preview the data at source. But when I run the mapping, I get the below error (See after SQL)

```
WITH curr
     AS (SELECT J."jira_issue_id",
                J.status_combined,
                J."issue_project_id",
                J."issue_user_key_reporter",
                J."issue_user_key_assignee",
                J."issue_summary",
                J."issue_description",
                J."issue_created_date",
                J."issue_due_date",
                J."issue_resolution_date",
                J."issue_updated_date",
                J."ji_project_name",
                J."ji_key",
                J."ji_type",
                J."ji_priority",
                J."ji_resolution",
                J."ji_status",
                J."issue_label",
                J."ji_component",
                J."fix_version",
                J."time_original_estimate",
                J."time_estimate_remaining",
                J."time_spent",
                J."sprint_name",
                J."sprint_start_date",
                J."sprint_end_date",
                J."sprint_complete_date",
                J.snap_date SNAP_DATE,
                J."data_source",
                J."category",
                d.*
         FROM   jira_issue_snap_v J
                left join dim_date d
                       ON To_date(snap_date, 'DD-MM-YY') = d.cal_date_current)
SELECT curr.*,
       PREV.ji_key                    JI_KEY_PREV,
       PREV.snap_date                 SNAP_DATE_PREV,
       PREV.status_combined           STATUS_COMBINED_PREV,
       PREV."time_original_estimate"  TIME_ORIGINAL_ESTIMATE_PREV,
       PREV."time_estimate_remaining" TIME_ESTIMATE_REMAINING_PREV
FROM   curr
       left join jira_issue_snap_v PREV
              ON curr.ji_key = PREV.ji_key
                 AND curr.cal_date_previous =
                     To_date(PREV.snap_date, 'DD-MM-YY')
ORDER  BY curr.ji_key
```

Below is the error string from logs:

```
FnName: Fetch Optimize -- [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Error in row.
FnName: Fetch Optimize -- [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Error in row.
....
....
....
....
FnName: Fetch Optimize -- [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
FnName: Fetch Optimize -- [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
FnName: Fetch Optimize -- [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
FnName: Fetch Optimize -- [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
```

My mapping currently consist of only source and target. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like - you/admin did not mention connection information correctly in the server where agent is running.

Comment: @KoushikRoy - Other queries pointing to the same connection works just fine.

Comment: Are you running above SQL in SQL Developer and Informatica with same DB user? Doed Infa user have proper access?

Comment: Yep, it is the same user.

Comment: I see the error `literal does not match format string` now. Order of column in source qualifier and in SQL arent matching. Please make sure order is same.

Comment: The order is same. I tried this query in other tools like Tableau, and it works juts fine.

Comment: is the data type same ? did you check? its not about other tools. Informaica should be able to convert data type from SQL to informatica data type. if there is mismatch, or if there is some columns unlinked from source qualifier, it can show this error.